# load .json file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink

I am using http://getuikit.com/docs/autocomplete.html as framework and try to make autocomplete function working. `countries.json` is inside public folder but app can't load it when i start typing country than i have error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

but link exist and work good when i try to call it by browser.

```
<div class="uk-autocomplete uk-form" data-uk-autocomplete="{source:'countries.json'}">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

[image]

remote file is ok:
http://powerful-reaches-2807.herokuapp.com/countries.json

chrome console show 404 but You can normally click on link and open it

[image]

Comment: You see.. there is an error with your routing. Show us your controller where the countries.json is created.

Comment: i dont have anything in controller. **countries.json** is just normal file here is code: https://github.com/ponciusz/x-company

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="uk-autocomplete uk-form" data-uk-autocomplete="{source:'http://localhost:3000/countries.json'}">
```

Is this on your local server?

If it works, you should use the path to the countries.json something like:

```
<div class="uk-autocomplete uk-form" data-uk-autocomplete="{source:'<%= path_to_countries_json %>'}">
```

Comment: yes local and Heroku not working i have this error:   **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/countries.json"):**

Comment: I see. if it does work locally, add following line in your app/config/environments/production.rb

config.serve_static_assets = true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `countries.json` existence, it's because the library requested a **POST** request (based on your rails log). You can only reach your files with **GET** method by default.

There are two options for you to overcome this issue:

1. Add a route so you can reach `countries.json` by POST request. (Not recommended)
2. Figure out why and how your library used POST request and make it a GET.